# Convert database field to time format

Tags: asp.net, datetime, session

I'm trying to make my string a nice formatted time but the column in the database isn't set up as a date/time field is there anyway I can do this?

Here's my query

```
Dim query as String = "Select * from openquery (devbook, 'SELECT wb.arrival_time FROM web_bookings wb ')"
```

And here's where i'm converting it

```
Session("formattime") = DateTime.Parse(drv.Row("arrival_time")).ToString("hh:mm")
```

The `arrival_time` field only has 4 numbers in like this `1000` so I need a way of converting it to a nice format like this `10:00AM`

I'm using VB by the way

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: Not sure whether it's relevant (I'm not an ASP.NET guy) but you don't even mention the SQL dialect nor the programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
string str = "1000";//drv.Row("arrival_time")
string[] formats = new string[] { "HHmm" };
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats,
                                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
string strTime = dt.ToShortTimeString();

DateTime dte = DateTime.Now;
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim str As String = "1000" 'drv.Row("arrival_time")
Dim formats As String() = New String() {"HHmm"}
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
Dim strTime As String = dt.ToShortTimeString()

Dim dte As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim culture As IFormatProvider = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", True)
```

**Outputs:**

10:00 AM

Alternatively, if you plan on using that frequently, you might want to add that as an extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToTime(this string str)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            string[] formats = new string[] { "HHmm" };
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats,
                                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        }
        catch
        { throw new Exception("Invalid data"); }
        return dt.ToShortTimeString();
    }
}
```

**--VB.NET--**

```
Public NotInheritable Class Extensions
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Shared Function ToTime(str As String) As String
        Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Try
            Dim formats As String() = New String() {"HHmm"}
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
        Catch
            Throw New Exception("Invalid data")
        End Try
        Return dt.ToShortTimeString()
    End Function
End Class
```

**Example:**

```
string str = "13000";//drv.Row("arrival_time")
string strTime = str.ToTime();
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim str As String = "13000"
'drv.Row("arrival_time")
Dim strTime As String = str.ToTime()
```

Anything bad in the data will throw you an exception.

**--EDIT--**

Works fine in VB.NET.

[image]

Comment: Seem to be getting  Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String' error with this one

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Please see my edit in response to your comment.

Comment: @KMan I converted it into VB.net the top one gives me an error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime and the bottom one gives me error Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String'

Comment: @KMan the last one you added gives me an error  'ToTime' is not a member of 'String'

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Please see my edit in response to your comment. Its works fine in VB.NET

Comment: @KMan I can get it to work by using "1000" but when changing that for my database field it errors? Any suggestions? Thanks for you help and patience

Comment: @KMan Here's is the error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. on Line 141: Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal) seems to be where the error is

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Can you verify the incoming data? This sounds like the incoming data is not `1000` or similar. Try debug mode and add a watch to see if its really for the format `1000`.

Comment: @KMan just had a look at my data it appears that some fields only have 3 characters "940" instead of "0940" is there anyway I can add the preceding "0" if it needs it?

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Yes, use `str = str.PadLeft(4, "0"c)`. This would pad left with zeros. Meaning `940` would be `0940`, and `40`=`0040` and `4`=`0004`.

Comment: @KMan thanks that works great - by the way how do you code in the comments? I see you have done this in your previous post

Comment: @Jamie Taylor: Same as you'd do in the editor, just that toolbar or shortcuts aren't available (0: For instance put your codes within the `(the grave accent key). Or for italics surround the text with * (star/asterisk).

Comment: @KMan Thanks again for your help and patience with me

Answer (score 0):

The date may contain more than just hours and minutes. You need to check what is in arrival time

Comment: I have added a bit above which says what's in my arrival_time field and what outcome I'm looking for

Comment: is the number an int or a string?

Comment: Then you cannont us DateTime, read it as a string. Then use substring to divide it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the VB.NET syntax, but I'm thinking you could just use `string.Split()` on the arrival time value, to split it into hours and minutes, then convert that into a DateTime.
`DateTime.Parse` won't automatically realise that those 4 numbers are supposed to be hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your input time is 3 or 4 digits representation of the time in 24 hour format that may have leading white space. You can then parse it like this:

```
Dim i As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(drv.Row("arrival_time")), NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, i) Then
  Dim hours As Int32 = i\100
  Dim minutes As Int32 = i Mod 100
  Dim ts As new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0)
  Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date + ts
  Session("formattime") = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Else
  ' Handle invalid time
End If
```

`DateTime.Parse` and friends is not able to parse time strings with only one digit for the hour hence this approach. Getting AM/PM right is not easy so that is delegated to the `DateTime` class.

Comment: This one doesn't error but it doesn't seem to work either it just gives me the else part output?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this 
http://blog.stevex.net/parsing-dates-and-times-in-net/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

If you need the colon in there, and can guarantee that your DB field will always return a string with 4 characters you can do something like this to get the time in the right format.

```
string e = "1000"; // from db.
string t = string.Format("{0}:{1}", e.Substring(0, 2), e.Substring(2, 2));
```

Comment: This works as you say if it is 4 numbers unfortunately there is some with three number they are missing the preceding 0 is there anyway I can add this on if there is 3 numbers?